# Unicode and string with encoding

Tags: string, unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-2.5

Why does this work:

```
a = 'a'.encode('utf-8')
print unicode(a)
>>> u'a'
```

And this will give me an Error:

```
b = 'b'.encode('utf-8_sig')
print unicode(b)
```

Saying: 
`>>> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't told `unicode` what encoding to use:

```
>>> a = 'a'.encode('utf-8')
>>> print unicode(a)
a
>>> b = 'b'.encode('utf-8_sig')
>>> print unicode(b)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print unicode(b)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print unicode(b, 'utf-8_sig')
b
```

Comment: Is unicode using 'utf-8' bei default or why i dont get an error in the first issue?

Comment: `'a'.encode('utf-8')` is just `'a'`, so you don't need to tell `unicode` how to deal with it, whereas `'b'.encode('utf-8_sig')` is `'\xef\xbb\xbfb'`

Answer (score 1):

`'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef` says two things:

1. `unicode(b)` uses `ascii` (`sys.getdefaultencoding()`) character encoding
2. `\xef` byte is not in ascii range. It is the first byte in [`BOM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) introduced by `'utf-8-sig'` encoding (used on Windows)

The first example works because `'a'` bytestring is ascii. `'a'.encode('utf-8')` is equivalent to `'a'.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding()).encode('utf-8')` and in this case it is equal to `'a'` itself.

In general, use `bytestring.decode(character_encoding) = unicode_string` and `unicode_string.encode(character_encoding) = bytestring`. bytestring is a sequence of bytes. Unicode string is a sequence of Unicode codepoints.

Do not call `.encode()` on bytestrings. `'a'` is a bytestring literal in Python 2. `u'a'` is a Unicode literal.